# How can I do float comparison in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, floating-point, comparison

```
lock_percent=$(echo "scale = 5; $value2*100/$value1" | bc)
value=`echo "$lock_percent" | bc`

    if [[ "$value" > "$8" ]]; then
       echo "Lock Percentage:$value percentage State Critical"
       exit $STATE_CRITICAL
    fi
```

I am not able to perform a float comparison with this. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bash itself can't use float. In this case maybe you can multiply by 10 or 100 (etc.) and get integer value which you can compare. Or, you can use **bc** comparison and return value:

```
echo "10.2>10.1" | bc
```

Comment: You could also do `bc <<< "10.2>10.1"`, which is faster :)

Answer (score 15):

```
# float number comparison
fcomp() {
    awk -v n1="$1" -v n2="$2" 'BEGIN {if (n1+0<n2+0) exit 0; exit 1}'
}

# test and example
fcomp_test() {
    if fcomp "$1" "$2"; then
       echo "$1<$2"
    else
       echo "$1>=$2"
    fi
}

fcomp_test 0.0 0.1
fcomp_test 0.1 0.1
fcomp_test -0.1 0.1
fcomp_test 1e3 1e4
fcomp_test -1.34e3 1.03e4
fcomp_test ' 0 ' ' 1 '
```

Comment: If you removed the `function` keyword, this would be much less bash-specific. Also consider `awk -v n1="$1" -v n2="$2"` and `fcomp "$1" "$2"` -- that way values aren't subject to string-splitting and glob expansion (sure, if this were used correctly they'll all be numbers, but better to make sure bad usage results in a nice useful error about an invalid number instead of a much more arbitrary bug).