# Bash string comparison

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I am trying to compare two strings in a Bash script and I am getting very strange results.

```
if [[ "010" < "01." ]]; then echo "Wrong"; else echo "OK"; fi
if [[ "010" < "01.0" ]]; then echo "Wrong"; else echo "OK"; fi
if [ "010" \< "01." ]; then echo "Wrong"; else echo "OK"; fi
if [ "010" \< "01.0" ]; then echo "Wrong"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

Reading the documentation, it seemed that `[[ < ]]` and `[ \< ]` should work the same, but they don't. It it seems that `[[ < ]]` works wrong when the strings don't have the same length. Am I missing something?

The expected result is 4 x `OK`. Tested on:

- CentOS release 6.4 (Final) - GNU Bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) (`OK Wrong OK OK`)
- [Ubuntu 14.04.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) LTS - GNU Bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) (`OK Wrong OK OK`)
- openSUSE 13.1 (Bottle) (x86_64) - GNU Bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) (`OK OK OK OK`)

Comment: Could you please add the output of the script?

Comment: The 2nd says Wrong to me on `GNU bash, version 4.3.39`.

Comment: I confirm strange behavior: output says: "OK, wrong, OK, OK"; while the expected output for me would have been "OK, wrong, OK, wrong"; since the values are sorted "01.", "010", "01.0" on my pc.

Comment: note that the strange behavior only occurs for limit case sorting; looks like a different sorting algorithm is used when using single vs double brackets; is that possible?

Comment: Looking at the ASCII table . comes before 0 so the expected order of strings should be 01., 01.0, 010

Comment: @Marin In other words, all 4 `if` conditions should fail and we should see `OK` for each one (which is what Bash 4.2.53 appears to be doing).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It should return 4 OK

Comment: on my pc (opensuse13.1-32, bash 4.2.53; `echo -e "01.0\n010\n01." | sort` gives "01.", "010", "01.0"; whence the expected output on my pc would be "ok, wrong, ok, wrong". So I guess this difference in sorting might be a hint at the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation from `help test`:

> STRING1 > STRING2
>
> True if STRING1 sorts after STRING2 lexicographically.

Taking your first `if` statement as an example:

```
if [[ "010" < "01." ]]; then echo "Wrong"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

In Bash the string `"01."` sorts lexicographically *before* the string `"010"` (you can test in other tools like Microsoft Excel), so the comparison returns false.  This is the case for all 4 of your comparisons.

Note that adding an additional `0` to the end of `"01."` doesn't change the ordering versus `"010"`, so you still get the same result.

Comment: I'm on bash 4.2.53 (opensuse13.1); and I get "OK, wrong, OK, OK"; so he does have a point...

Comment: I'm also on Bash 4.2.53 and I get OK for all 4.  This is really strange.

Comment: when I sort the three values; I get: "01." , "010", "01.0"

Comment: Strange indeed. On OSX running bash 3.2.* I get `OK`, `OK`, `OK`, `OK`. On AWS Linux running bash 4.1.2 I get `OK`, `Wrong`, `OK`, `OK`.

Comment: You might say that I'm feeling a bit `bash`ful for posting this answer.  How can explain the OP then?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that starting with Bash 4.1 the < and > string comparison operators respect the locale.

So between two systems you can have the following differences:

1. different locales - check by running `locale` (for a meaning of the different locale settings, see *[What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do/87763#87763)*)
2. even if the locales are the same, shopt compat31 or compat32 might be switched on (Bash 3.1 or 3.2 compatibility mode), which means that the string comparisons would not respect locale - check by running `shopt`

Further reading:

- *[New features added to Bash 5.1](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)* (look under 4.1 point q.)
- *[What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do/87763#87763)*
- *[4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)* (see compat31 and compat32)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare integers you shall do this:

```
if [[ 10 < 1 ]]; then echo "10 < 1"; else echo "10 > 1"; fi

# Result:
#
#   10 > 1
```

If you want to compare floats you should look at this thread:
*[How can I do float comparison in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541568/how-to-do-float-comparison-in-bash)*

For your example:

```
echo "10 < 1.0" | bc
# Return: 0

echo "10 > 1.0" | bc
# Return: 1
```

Comment: Well I am a bit confused to see this answer as incorrect. Here is a sample of commands : mat@lapdev001:~$ if [[ 11 < 10 ]]; then echo "<"; else echo ">";fi
>
mat@lapdev001:~$ if [[ 11 < 25 ]]; then echo "<"; else echo ">";fi
<
And for string comparison : mat@lapdev001:~$ if [[ "longstring" >  "string" ]]; then echo "<"; else echo ">";fi
>
mat@lapdev001:~$ if [[ "string" >  "string" ]]; then echo "<"; else echo ">";fi
>
mat@lapdev001:~$ if [[ "string" >  "longstring" ]]; then echo "<"; else echo ">";fi
<

Comment: Please [edit (change) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31386294/edit) to add additional information, not here in comments (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Comments can be deleted at any time.